# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, encoding

I have a list of unicode objects and want to encode them to utf-8, but encoding doesn't seem to work.

the code is here  :

```
>>> tmp = [u' test context']
>>> tmp.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
>>>
```

I can't understand why there is no attribute encode

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to do `encode` on `tmp[0]`, not on `tmp`.

`tmp` is not a string.  It *contains* a (Unicode) string.

Try running `type(tmp)` and `print dir(tmp)` to see it for yourself.

Comment: **tmp is not a string. It contains a (Unicode) string.**    yeap u r absolute right !! thnx a lot!

Answer (score 10):

You need to unicode each element of the list individually

```
[x.encode('utf-8') for x in tmp]
```