# Converting Unicode strings to Ascii strings, in a dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054333/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-encode) and still am getting the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'`.

I've tried

```
dic = pickle.load(fileObject)
for v in dic:
    v.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

and

```
dic = pickle.load(fileObject)
for key, val in dic.iteritems():
    val.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

and still get the same error. When printing out the variables they all display with a `u` at the front. The dictionary was pickled under python 3 and is being unpickled in python 2.

I tried     `pp.pprint((dataFromPrevMod).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` and it didn't work.

If I `pprint` out the dictionary, it shows its contents but in Python 3 each line starting with a `u` for example `u'website': u'exmample.org'`

Dictionary pretty printed in Python 3

```
{
        'output': {
                'table': 'intersection',
                'file_location': '\\\\storage1\\tpn\\tpn_team\\dev\\asmithe\\',
                'schema': 'asmithe',
                'temporary_location': '\\\\storage1\\tpn\\tpn_team\\dev\\asmithe\
\'
        },
        'tpn_inventory_db_r': {
                'generic_pwd': '51f3tlNE26',
                'db_name': 'tpn',
                'user': 'asmithe',
                'schema': 'asmithe',
                'host': 'example.tpns.org'
        },
        'proj_year': '2005',
        'proj_rules_r': 'C:\\asmithe\\rules.txt',
        'incidents_db_r': {
                'schema': 'tpn_pp_dist',
                'generic_pwd': '51f3tlNE26',
                'db_name': 'tpn',
                'user': 'asmithe',
                'fire_table': 'incident',
                'host': 'example.tpns.org'
        },
        'plots_to_project_r': 'C:\\Users\\asmithe\\Plots.txt',
        'tpn_proj_db_r': {
                'generic_pwd': '51f3tlNE26',
                'db_name': 'tpn inventory',
                'user': 'asmithe',
                'schema': 'test',
                'host': 'example.tpns.org'
        }
}
```

Dictionary pretty printed in Python 2 (notice the addition of u)

```
{   u'incidents_db_r': {   u'db_name': u'tpn',
                                u'fire_table': u'incident',
                                u'generic_pwd': u'51f3tlNE26',
                                u'host': u'example.tpns.org',
                                u'schema': u'tpn_pp_dist',
                                u'user': u'asmithe'},
    u'tpn_inventory_db_r': {   u'db_name': u'tpn',
                                 u'generic_pwd': u'51f3tlNE26',
                                 u'host': u'example.tpns.org',
                                 u'schema': u'asmithe',
                                 u'user': u'asmithe'},
    u'tpn_proj_db_r': {   u'db_name': u'tpn inventory',
                            u'generic_pwd': u'51f3tlNE26',
                            u'host': u'example.tpns.org',
                            u'schema': u'test',
                            u'user': u'asmithe'},
    u'output': {   u'file_location': u'\\\\storage1\\tpn\\tpn_team\\dev\\asmithe\ \',
                   u'schema': u'asmithe',
                   u'table': u'intersection',
                   u'temporary_location': u'\\\\storage1\\tpn\\tpn_team\\dev\\asmithe idek\\'},
    u'plots_to_project_r': u'C:\\Users\\asmithe\\Plots.txt',
    u'proj_rules_r': u'C:\\asmithe\\rules.txt',
    u'proj_year': u'2005'}
```

Comment: Note: The first for loop iterates over the keys, `v` might not be the best variable name. What are `type(key)` and  `type(val)`? Currently looks like there's a nested dictionary in there.

Comment: Also, can you show what `print(val)` ?

Comment: Are you sure valuee are not already unicode strings? Cause it is the default in python3. But the first problem is that `data` is not what you think it is... Do a nice `import pprint` `pprint.pprint(data)`

Comment: @Maresh no no, they ARE in unicode but when I do pprint they have extra u's added to them. That's what I'm trying to do, get rid of the u's.

Comment: Also, remember that Python strings are immutable. Calling something like `val.encode(whatever)` creates and returns a *new string* to you, leaving the original unmodified. In this code, you ignore that new string value, which probably isn't want you want.

Comment: @Maresh - as noted in the tag, the OP is using Python 2.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 He mentionned data has been pickled from Python3 that's why I ask. @Celeritas, the pprint is just to show us what `data` is exactly, because from the error you report it sounds like it's actually nested dicts.

Comment: @Celeritas, we'd like to see the output of `pprint` or `print` or `type` :) See my previous comment.

Comment: *Where* are the `u''`s showing up? They certainly appear in `repr(u'äöü')`, but `print(u'äöü')` should properly decode unicode to the terminals proper encoding.

Comment: @Maresh - exactly. It's pickled in Python 3, so the OP can indeed be sure that they are Unicode strings. However, Unicode strings in Python 2 have a `u` prefix, so the OP wants to make them _not_ Unicode.

Comment: Yes. I figured he wanted from bytes to str, my bad. @Celeritas full output pls, `pprint(data)`? From your error message `data` sounds like it is: `{ 'one': {...} }`  so you're trying to call `.encode` on a dict, not a string, that's what we want to verify.

Comment: @Maresh ok added full output. I'm really not trying to do anything complicated, just use the variables in a dictionary. BTW, I think you're right about the nested thing. So how do I iterate through a nested dictionary and convert everything to ascii? Do I need to convert everything to ascii? I just want to use the values to connect to the database.

Comment: Thx. So that's what I though, you have nested dicts :) You need to do that recursively and test what the type of the value is. Check my answer

Comment: @Celeritas So, did any of the answers below help you? If you problem is solved mark it as so please :)

Comment: @Maresh no not fully. There's too many commands I don't understand such as `isinstance` and `self`

Comment: Isinstance just check wether the value is a dict or a unicode string, you can just run the code I provided it will do the trick, cause I don't think you need the keys as bytes

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `pprint` shows unicode strings as `u'bla'` is that in Python 2, `string` and `unicode` objects are both sequence types, but *they are not the same*.

So it is logical that `pprint` in Python 2 doesn't show them as such.

Comment: Does it matter in the sense I just want to use the values to connect to the database with?

Comment: @Celeritas - Have you tried connecting to the database with these values yet?

Comment: @Celeritas It depends on the format of the data in the database. If you encode the string as UTF-8 and the database uses UTF-16, it's probably not going to match. But you'd have to encode the unicode text in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested dicts, so you need something like this (done very quickly just to give you an idea):

```
def unicode_to_bytes(d):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            unicode_to_bytes(d[k])
        elif isinstance(d[k], unicode):
            d[k] = d[k].encode('ascii', 'ignore')

test = {
    'a': u'b',
    'b': {
        'c': u'c',
        'd': {'e': u'f'}
    }
}

unicode_to_bytes(test)

print test
```

This is not taking care of keys though.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How about `d[str(k)] = str(d[k]); del d[k]`?

Comment: You'd get: *RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration* with the `del` And also: *UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character* if you don't specify you want to ignore non-ascii.

Comment: Yes, I guess there's many ways to approach this thing, let's leave him figure out the rest on his own :-P

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness: It's astoundingly complex to write a custom pickler that automatically encodes unicode objects to strings. The below is for Python 2 only:

```
import pickle
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

class EncodingUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def __init__(self, f, encoding=None):
        pickle.Unpickler.__init__(self, f)
        # we don't want to modify the class variable from pickle.Unpickler
        self.dispatch = self.dispatch.copy()
        self.dispatch[pickle.UNICODE] = EncodingUnpickler.load_unicode
        self.dispatch[pickle.BINUNICODE] = EncodingUnpickler.load_binunicode
        self.encoding = encoding or sys.getdefaultencoding()

    def load_binunicode(self):
        pickle.Unpickler.load_binunicode(self)
        self.append(self.stack.pop().encode(self.encoding))

    def load_unicode(self):
        pickle.Unpickler.load_unicode(self)
        self.append(self.stack.pop().encode(self.encoding))


d = { u'1': u'a', u'2': u'b' }
s = pickle.dumps(d)
unp = EncodingUnpickler(StringIO(s))
du = unp.load()
print du
```